# Why has SSL v3 not yet been upgraded to a higher version with stronger principles, what are the dependencies and issues to do so?

Tags: encryption, tls

SSLv3 is almost 18 years old; why has it not been updated to a more advanced version with stronger rules and structure. What have been the issues and dependencies in doing so till now???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS 1.0 is in effect SSL 3.1. If you need more details about the history and why it is called TLS 1.0 instead of SSL 3.1 read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).